# Python print next line while printing from for loop

Tags: python, match

I am performing a for loop on a list and would like to find a match and print the next line.  However, when I try to use the next() method I keep getting a failure. Can I please get some help in extracting the next line after a specified match?

string (for loop output):

```
item_0
0
item_1
0           




item_3
727

item_4
325
```

For Loop to find match and next line:

```
result = tree.xpath('//tr/td/font/text()')

for line in result:
    if 'item_3' in line:
        print(line.next())
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: '_ElementStringResult' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` is a `lxml.etree._ElementStringResult` (a modified `str`) in your code. `lxml.etree._ElementStringResults` do not have a `next` method which is why you are getting an `AttributeError`.

You can set a flag indicating that the next line should be printed as follows:

```
print_line = False
for line in result:
    if print_line:
        print(line)
        print_line = False
    if 'item_3' in line:
        print_line = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Is there another way I can accomplish getting the next line?

Comment: That is very cool and clever. Still very new to programming and need to think outside the box. Worked great, thanks.

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but try:

```
result = tree.xpath('//tr/td/font/text()')

iter_result = iter(result)
for line in iter_result:
    if 'item_3' in line:
        print(next(iter_result))
```

Comment: this skips printable lines if `item_3` is on successive lines